# Choosing View or Activity in Android programming?

Tags: android, layout, view, android-activity

I am creating an interface like Powerpoint.

a Powerpoint document has several presentation pages.
I want to display a page to edit and the others as a list on the left.

Should I create each page as an Activity, or a View?

It would be thankful if you clear my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easiest to display the list of pages in an Activity Fragment on the left and the current selection as an Activity Fragment on the right. You can reload the right Fragment with different contents whenever the user selects a different page to display. You don't need to create a separate Activity Fragment for each page—that would be a lot of overhead for no good reason. Depending on what kind of data you have for a "page", the right-hand Fragment might contain a single custom View or it may require a complex view hierarchy.

See the [guide topic on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for a tutorial introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Each page is an Activity. A View class is an object on screen - an edit box, a check box, an image, etc., or a set of elements on screen. An Activity is code that manipulates data and view object to provide some functionality, its your workflow. If you think in terms of the MVC pattern, Views are the views in MVC. Activities are the controller.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)s together.